# how can we get 2 vertexes path?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Now I have the query below and I would like to get all the edge and It is interesting why we got 2 same path and I want to get the path detail. How can I implement?

`Vertex fromNode = g.V().has('name', 'alice').next();Vertex toNode = g.V().has('name', 'bobby').next();g.V(fromNode).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).path()
==>[v[4224],v[40964296]]
==>[v[4224],v[40964296]]
==>[v[4224],v[4144],v[40964256],v[4096],v[40964296]]`

We have the Graph below.

```
gremlin> a = graph.addVertex("name", "alice")
==>v[4208]
gremlin> b = graph.addVertex("name", "bobby")
==>v[40968424]
gremlin> c = graph.addVertex("name", "cindy")
==>v[4192]
gremlin> d = graph.addVertex("name", "david")
==>v[40972520]
gremlin> e = graph.addVertex("name", "eliza")
==>v[40964272]
gremlin> a.addEdge("rates",b,"tag","ruby","value",9)
==>e[2ry-38w-azv9-oe3fs][4208-rates->40968424]
gremlin> b.addEdge("rates",c,"tag","ruby","value",8)
==>e[odzq5-oe3fs-azv9-38g][40968424-rates->4192]
gremlin> c.addEdge("rates",d,"tag","ruby","value",7)
==>e[170-38g-azv9-oe6lk][4192-rates->40972520]
gremlin> d.addEdge("rates",e,"tag","ruby","value",6)
==>e[oe04d-oe6lk-azv9-oe08g][40972520-rates->40964272]
gremlin> a.addEdge("rates",e,"tag","java","value",9)
==>e[366-38w-azv9-oe08g][4208-rates->40964272]
gremlin> g.E().values("tag")
==>ruby
==>ruby
==>ruby
==>ruby
==>java
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
```

I would like to get the path detail like below:

```
==>bobby=[v[0], e[10][0-rates->2], v[2]]
==>cindy=[v[0], e[10][0-rates->2], v[2], e[11][2-rates->4], v[4]]
==>david=[v[0], e[10][0-rates->2], v[2], e[11][2-rates->4], v[4], e[12][4-rates->6], v[6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify that you want the edges as well by traversing over them explicitly:

```
gremlin> g.V(fromNode).repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).path()
==>[v[0],e[10][0-rates->2],v[2]]
==>[v[0],e[14][0-rates->8],v[8],e[13][6-rates->8],v[6],e[12][4-rates->6],v[4],e[11][2-rates->4],v[2]]
```

Comment: where can I find the functions like otherV(),simplePath()? any document or  resources I can refer?

Comment: all the steps are in the documentation: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-traversal-steps